# Deleted record keeps reappearing in data file using MS Word 10 merge/Excel 10 spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, merge

I am unable to remove one particular record from my data file. I remove it from the excel spreadsheet, but when I try to merge it is back--even after I have changed the file name after removing the record, and even after I have copied my data and saved it under a new name without the offending record. When I go to merge, that record is back. I can't remember every time I use that data source to uncheck that one record; I just want it gone. Can you help me?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're importing data into your spreadsheet via a connection to an external source like a text file, CSV, XML, database etc., right? Now if you delete a row from your spreadsheet and then refresh the connection, of course it will reimport that row as well from the source. Delete the offending record from the source if you don't want it to end up in your  spreadsheet after importing.

Comment: Sorry, Karen. I am using an .xlsx Excel file. I remove the offending line from the .xlsx file. I go to Word and start a Merge to e-mail. I go down to the Data Source box and the file's name shows up--even if I change the name of the file, the new name is in the Data Source box. When I click om that Data Source and then go into Edit Recipient List, the record that I deleted shows up again. You mention refreshing the connection. Maybe I don't understand how to do this, would you explain please? Many thanks, this is making me crazy.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're trying to do now. Must admit I'm not a mail merge expert, but I created a simple XLSX with 2 cols: Name & Address, added 5 rows, saved and closed. Then I started Word's mail merge wizard & added these 2 values in a simple letter. Preview shows all 5 names & addresses inserted properly. Now I went back to Excel & deleted 2 rows. Back to Word, ran the wizard again & now I see only 3 names & addresses, as expected. If you're using a different procedure, can you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/900583/edit) your question to include the *exact* steps so we can replicate?

Comment: What  you did is exactly what I have done for years, and what is not working now. This one, particular record will not stay deleted when I call the file up as a data file. It doesn't show when I open the file in Excel, but when I call it up as a data file, the one record is there. I had to delete two records at the same work session; one has stayed gone but this one keeps coming back. . . . remember that old song, "The Cat Came Back?" That's what I seem to have here. It is definitely mysterious, and very, very frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: Strange. Can you try opening the XLSX, Saving As a new file and using that instead?

Comment: Been there, done that, it still repopulates the data file with that one record. I really appreciate all your help, but I think that God or the universe or Mother Nature wants that one person to continue getting my emails. I'm going to not worry about it. It's not that she asked to be removed from the list, it's that she passes my info on to people I'd rather didn't have it. I need to let go and figure that there's a cosmic reason that they need my info. Thanks again!

Comment: If the universe wills it then so be it. :) Perhaps someone else will be able to replicate and solve your issue though.